# Help Calculating My "Deviation"

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, probability-or-statistics, code-review, broken-code

I created a "distribution deviation" where for $\left\{a_1,...,a_k\right\}$ we take all take the mean of all combinations of $\frac{\min\left\{a_{i},a_{j}\right\}}{\max\left\{a_{i},a_j\right\}}$ ($i,j\in\left\{1,...,k\right\}$) without repetitions, subtract by one and take the absolute value.

$$\left|1-\frac{1}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}i}\sum_{j=2}^{k}\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}\frac{\min\left\{a_{i},a_{j}\right\}}{\max\left\{a_{i},a_{j}\right\}}\right|$$

For infinite $k$ we simply take

$$\left|1-\frac{2}{k(k-1)}\sum_{j=1}^{k}\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}\frac{\min\left\{a_{i},a_{j}\right\}}{\max\left\{a_{i},a_{j}\right\}}\right|$$

This works well for values of $a_i$ that are extremely small.

I want to apply this deviation to the differences of elements in the folner sequence of $\left\{\frac{\ln(m)}{\ln(n)}:m\in\mathbb{N}_{>0},n\in\mathbb{N}_{>1}\right\}\cap[0,1]$. The folner sequence is

$$g(d)=\left\{\frac{\ln(m)}{\ln(n)}:m\in\mathbb{N}_{>0},n\in\mathbb{N}_{>1},n\le d\right\}\cap[0,1]$$

For every $d\in\mathbb{R}$, if we list $g(d)$ (note $g(d)$ is finite) as $\left\{a_1,...,a_{k}\right\}$ ($k$ is the number of elements in the list depending on $d\in\mathbb{R}$) we take $|a_{i+1}-a_i|$ where $i,j\in\left\{1,...,k\right\}$. My distribution deviation as $d,k\to\infty$.

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|1-\frac{2}{k(k-1)}\sum_{j=2}^{k}\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}\frac{\min\left\{a_{j+1}-a_{j},a_{i+1}-a_{i}\right\}}{\max\left\{a_{j+1}-a_{j},a_{i+1}-a_{i}\right\}}\right|$$

Here is my attempt to do this

```
F[d_] := Abs[
   Differences[
    DeleteDuplicates[
     Sort[Flatten[
       Table[Log[m]/Log[n], {n, 2, d}, {m, 1, Floor[n]}]]]]]];
G[d_] := Table[
  N[Min[F[d][[i]], F[d][[j]]]/Max[F[d][[i]], F[d][[j]]], 10], {j, 2, 
   Length[F[100]]}, {i, 1, j - 1}]
```

Unfortunately it takes too long to load. Is there a way to shorten the time? Does my code match my math equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can speed up the calculations for your initial equation several orders of magnitude (with ever larger increases in speed for larger values of `k`) by using `Sort` and `Accumulate`:

```
(* Generate a random sample of positive numbers *)
k = 100;
SeedRandom[12345];
x = RandomVariate[ChiSquareDistribution[20], k];

(* Original equation *)
t1 = AbsoluteTiming[Abs[1 - (2/(k (k - 1))) Sum[Min[x[[i]], x[[j]]]/Max[x[[i]], x[[j]]],
  {j, 2, k}, {i, 1, j - 1}]]]
(* {0.0120628, 0.262134} *)

(* Updated equation *)
t2 = AbsoluteTiming[y1 = Sort[x]; y2 = Accumulate[y1]; 
  Abs[1 - (2/(k (k - 1))) Sum[y2[[j - 1]]/y1[[j]], {j, 2, k}]]]
(* {0.0001317, 0.262134} *)

(* Ratio of timings *)
t1[[1]]/t2[[1]]
(* 91.593 *)
```

For `k = 1000` the ratio of timings is around 1,100.

**Addition:**

Here is a general formula for your index.  (I have left off any removal of duplicates as I'm a bit skeptical about the usefulness even without the fact that duplicates cause problems.)

```
deviation[a_] := Module[{a1, a2},
  a1 = Sort[a, Less];
  a2 = Accumulate[a1];
  Abs[1 - (2/(Length[a] (Length[a] - 1))) Sum[a2[[j - 1]]/a1[[j]], {j, 2, Length[a]}]]]
```

Using a list of numbers from above the deviation index is found with

```
deviation[x]
(* 0.278869 *)
```

And the same index on the differences is found with

```
deviation[Differences[x]]
(* 1.62546 *)
```

Using your function `F` I get the following:

```
x = F[5]
```

[image: F[5]]

```
deviation[x] // N
(* 0.470385 *)
deviation[Differences[x]] // N
(* 0.821658 *)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if my equation matches my description. Can you double-check.

Comment: It would be good if you provided the code for your original equation.  Then you could proceed to the adjustment for the differences which should be identical to the original equation - other than now you have k-1 differences.  No need to create an equation specially for the differences.

Comment: `F[d_] := Abs[
   Differences[
    DeleteDuplicates[
     Sort[Flatten[
       Table[Log[m]/Log[n], {m, 1, Floor[d]}, {n, 2, Floor[m]}]]]]]];
G[d_] := Flatten[
   Table[N[Min[F[d][[i]], F[d][[j]], 10]/Max[F[d][[i]], F[d][[j]]], 
     10], {j, 2, Length[F[d]]}, {i, 1, j - 1}]];
N[1 - Mean[G[15]], 10]`. Here is my original code. I applied my deviation to the Folner Sequence of $\left\{\frac{\ln(m)}{\ln(n)}:m\in\mathbb{N_{>1}},n\in\mathbb{N_{>2}}\right\}\cap[0,1]$. (Take $n<d\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$). Check if your code gives the same result.

Comment: You've got 3 different questions:  (1) How to code the "deviation", (2) How to code when the differences are used, and (3) how to use the functions for the Folner sequence.  The answer to (1) should tell you how to do the other 2 questions.

Comment: I am sure how to adjust your code.I should get `.6542...` instead I get `.9999...`. I believe it should be $\frac{2}{k(k-1)}$ but I am not sure what it should be instead.

Comment: I apologize just help me correct this and I will accept your answer.

Comment: It is I who should apologize.  I forgot that `Sort` sorts in canonical order and I should have told it to sort in numerical order.  For things like `F[5]` which results in terms looking like `-(Log[3]/Log[5]) + Log[4]/Log[5]` requires including the option "Less".  I'll add that to the answer.  If that now doesn't match with what you expect, then we'll go from there.

Comment: Thanks. This works.